# Get mongoose model by text value in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Example

```
const dict = require('../models/dictionary/')

const model = req.query.model
var query = dict.model.find({}) //doesn't  work
var query = dict.AutoDict.find({}) //works
```

- **dict** - contain mongoose models (for instance "AutoDict")
- model - get name(text value for instance "AutoDict" ) from front-end

How to do, that code `var query = dict.model.find({})` started work?

Comment: How are you exporting the models?

Comment: I've declared them in "../models/dictionary/index.js" and after import to const dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to use a variable to reach to an object field, you need to reference it within brackets:

```
var query = dict[model].find({})
```